Instance variables as default values in methods
When I have this code:
class A:

    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p

    def flash(self, i = self.p):
        return i*i

a = A(2)
print(a)

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xan/tmp/z.py", line 1, in <module>
    class A:
    ...<5 lines>...
            return i*i
  File "/home/xan/tmp/z.py", line 6, in A
    def flash(self, i = self.p):
                        ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Why I can't have instance variables as default values?

I know I can have a tricky: def flash(self, i = None): if i == None: i = self.p .... but I want to know WHY I can't do that.

The first, accepted answer to the duplicate starts with: "You can't really define this as the default value, since the default value is evaluated when the method is defined which is before any instances exist. " and explains it further. What do you find unclear in it?

@somenxavier because there is no variable self in the scope of the class body, where you define the function.

so, just open up a fresh Python REPL and do def foo(x, y=2*x): pass and see what error you get... (it will be a NameError, can you guess which name isn't defined?)
